# GraphQL Apollo Cannot Return Null for non-nullable

Tags: node.js, express, graphql, apollo

I'm trying to learn graphql so that I can apply it to a React website. I'm having some trouble right now with it though and cannot figure out why it says that null is being returned when I am 100% certain that what is being returned is not null. If I print `results` in the resolver it prints an array of user objects as expected, but when it returns it says that I'm returning null for the field `Query.users`. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Query: { // graphql query resolver
    users: function (parent, args, { User }) {
        var mongoose = require('mongoose');
        var array = [];
        mongoose.connect('localhost:27017', function(err){
            if(err) throw err;
            User.find({}).then(results=>{
                console.log(results);
                return results;
            });
        });
    }
}

type Query { //query typedef
    users: [User]!
}

type User { // graphql schema typedef
    _id: String!
    username: String!,
    email: String!,
    joined: String,
    interests: [String],
    friends: [User]
}

var User = new Schema({ // mongoose schema def
   username: !String,
   email: !String,
   joined: String,
   interests: [String],
   friends: [[this]]
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you are not returning anything in your `users` function.

You can await and return the resolved promise value like below. Try this and check if you still are not able to get the users list from your query.

```
users: function (parent, args, { User }) {
  return await getUsers()
}


const getUsers = () => {
  var mongoose = require('mongoose');
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    mongoose.connect('localhost:27017', function(err){
      if(err) 
        reject(err);  
      User.find({}).then(results=>{
        console.log(results);
        resolve(results);
      });
    });        
  });  
}
```

The code I added has ES6, please convert it to ES5 if that is what you use through out your app.

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much.